# Find the path to the nearest tree to the player

Tags: minecraft, bukkit, path-finding

I am trying to write a command where I want the player (or custom NPC using citizensAPI) to go the nearest tree and cut it. How should I go about implementing this.

So to give you some details, I want the location of the nearest tree or wood block. After this I want to create an ArrayList that has the coordinates of the path on which the NPC can move to that location.

Comment: Look into https://github.com/cabaletta/baritone for an implementation of pathfinding in Minecraft.

Comment: Take inspiration from the [Citizens AI](https://github.com/CitizensDev/Citizens2/tree/master/main/src/main/java/net/citizensnpcs/npc/ai). That is an example of pathfinding in Spigot for Minecraft.

Comment: @Lucan Are you talking about their implementation of A star navigation strategy? I think that is a good starting point. But I can't see any method that gives the path as a vector if I pass npc and location as parameters. Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a cuboid around the NPC's current location and iterate its blocks until you find a wood block. Then you can use the `GoalController` of the NPC and add the "walking"-goal. The corresponding class would be `MoveToGoal`. Then you can create `BlockBreaker` to have the NPC break the wood.